# Searching within the project using the VS Code FTP extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, search, ftp, sftp

I am unable to search within the project using the VS Code FTP extension. The files are not visible.

[image]

Comment: you have a screenshot of the `Find in Files` bar, I do not see any FTP, if you use a virtual workspace located on an FTP site it should work

Comment: @rioV8 Which plugin are you using? Can you share an example video?